# php get array index of object having specific key value

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array

I need to test if a specific key/value exists and then return the array index that the key/value is a member of without having to loop through each element and/or levels of the array.  Is this possible?

```
 [0: 
     { regional:
          [ 0 :
               {
               ID: 1000
               someInfoA : valueA
               someInfoB : valueB
               }
          ]
          [ 1 :
               {
               ID: 1001
               someInfoA : valueA
               someInfoB : valueB
               }
          ]
          [ 2 :
               {
               ID: 1002
               someInfoA : valueA
               someInfoB : valueB
               }
          ]
          [ 3 :
               {
               ID: 1003
               someInfoA : valueA
               someInfoB : valueB
               }
          ]
     }
     { national : 
       [ ... ]
       [ ... ]
     }
]
```

In this data example, I need to see if `ID: 1002` exists and if it does, return the array index: `[2]`, if not return `false`.  i have seen various ways of just determining if the key/value exists but I haven't seen a non-loop method for returning the array index it belongs to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a combination of [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_search()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php). Have a look [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b462d47bc0f5b63dc4e5846ebefebf5e4eeb046).

```
$records = [
    [
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ]
];
$key = array_search(3245, array_column($records, 'id'));
echo $key;
```

Comment: BRILLIANT!  Thank you.  I tested this and it works perfect.  But what if the ID value isn't found - what does it return?  I tested and $key was blank - is that an empty `""` value?

Comment: If not found, it returns [false](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#refsect1-function.array-search-returnvalues)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array_column() to create a new array with id as key. You have then all fields in direct access.

```
$arrWithIdAsKey = array_column($records, null, 'id');

echo "<pre>".var_export($arrWithIdAsKey,true)."</pre>";
```

Example Output:

```
array (
  2135 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2135,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
  ),
  3245 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3245,
    'first_name' => 'Sally',
    'last_name' => 'Smith',
  ),
  5342 => 
  array (
    'id' => 5342,
    'first_name' => 'Jane',
    'last_name' => 'Jones',
  ),
  5623 => 
  array (
    'id' => 5623,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
  ),
)
```